# What kind of information is a police officer in Germany allowed to ask, in random situations on the street, e.g., during a traffic check?

Tags: police, germany, human-rights

For reference: There is the well-known argument, especially in the U.S., that you should not talk to the police, like here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d-7o9xYp7eE in one of the extremest forms. There are lots of videos online of people being stopped in their cars and then going on for 30 minutes to "plead the fifth" while the cop asks the same question over and over again. For example, in the U.S., the key words seem to be "am I detained, am I free to go"; and by the way they are *always* used exactly like this, I assume they are not just randomly used, but with some kind of precedent.

Question: What kind of information is a police officer in Germany allowed to ask, in random situations on the street, e.g., during a traffic check? Presumably name and address, and whatever is on the Personalausweis? Is there a particular (verbatim) sentence that can be used in German if you do not wish to answer a question, without making yourself suspicious?

As a very concrete example: I was stopped in a generic traffic check once, late at night, in a very peaceful area where *nothing* ever happens, and was asked where I just came from. I truthfully answered "from the gym" or something like that and that was it. At the time, it seemed simply like small talk; they were friendly, I was friendly, they had a look at my documents, and we were done with it. But it certainly *was* the kind of situation those U.S. videos seem to be about; i.e. I *could* pretty easily have been forced into a situation where I had to lie or implicate myself, without even knowing.

I know that there are political groups with very strong opinions in Germany who will tell us to not utter a single word to an officer, but would prefer to know what the judicative has to say on this. Are there well-known precedent cases?  Are there official formulations which are recognizable to an officer to mean "I am aware of my rights, and would prefer not to make an issue of this, but don't want to keel over right away"? Or is this more of a cat-and-mouse game, usually? Is there a (publicised) policy about this in the police community?

Comment: '"am I detained, am I free to go" [...] always used exactly like this [...] with some kind of precedent.' That rings alarm bells for me, as it sounds very similar to Sovereign Citizen 'techniques' ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sovereign_citizen_movement ), wherein very precise phrases are given near-magical status and used in the (mistaken) belief that they have a particular power.

Comment: @owjburnham, yup, that's partly why the question came up to me - the view we get (from outside of the US, and especially through Youtube) may or may not be very distorted... I would like to know if this topic generally is talked about in law circles (universities, police, law system itself) in a more neutral fashion.

Comment: @owjburnham  I'm not so sure what's wrong with stating those words exactly like that if it invokes a certain right. Or would exercising one's rights be also akin to 'sovereign citizen techniques' - in other words, just do what you're told?

Comment: @owjburnham those phrases aren't magic words but they're the most straightforward way of determining whether you've been detained or, on the other hand, if the conversation is "consensual."  The questions are based in 4th amendment jurisprudence rather than on crackpot theories.

Comment: In the specific case of "Am I being detained?" in the USA I believe that it is a real thing rather than a crackpot legal theory. Courts have decided in the past that someone who doesn't exercise their right to leave has waived it, despite an impression given at the time that they were not free to just walk away. Asking this question forces the police officer to resolve the ambiguity. https://www.columbuscriminaldefenseattorney.com/blog/am-i-being-detained-6-questions-you-should-ask-during-interactions-with-the-police/

Comment: @owjburnham "Am  I detained or am I free to Go" is wording recommended by the ACLU based on the language of court decisions. If the officer says that you are not free to go, or stops you if you try to leave, then you are technically under arrest and the Miranda rules apply.

Comment: That’s USA. In Germany, you are free to ask of course. I bet there will be people in the uk, Germany and elsewhere asking for their Miranda rights to be read. In Germany, the police officer has a third answer if they stopped your car: “You are free to go after I see your driving license and your car registration “.

Comment: @owjburnham, what David Seigel said above.  Adding to that, police also have their own unique script that they are hesitant to deviate from as you may have noticed.  e.g. "*I need to see your ID*" over, and over, and over...  Truly the plethora of repetitive videos out there is astounding.  The phrase that rings alarm bells for you is simply citizens asserting their rights.  That shouldn't be alarming at all.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [German Bar Association](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_Bar_Association) published an article about your rights in traffic controls ([***Polizei­kon­trolle: Das sind Ihre Rechte***](https://anwaltauskunft.de/magazin/mobilitaet/verkehr/polizeikontrolle-das-sind-ihre-rechte), July 2018) and an article about your rights in identity checks ([***Was darf die Polizei bei einer Perso­nen­kon­trolle?***](https://anwaltauskunft.de/magazin/gesellschaft/strafrecht-polizei/was-darf-die-polizei-bei-einer-personenkontrolle), June 2018).

#### Traffic check

You do have to

- answer questions for determining your identity (see section about identity check).
- show the car registration document.
- show your driving licence.
- leave the vehicle (if asked to).
- show the legally required equipment (medical kit etc.).

You don’t have to

- answer questions like "Why do you think you were stopped?" or "Where are you coming from?".
- admit a crime/offense.
- agree to a test (breathalyser, urine, blood, pupil reaction etc.).
- let them enter or search through your vehicle (unless in the case of *Gefahr im Verzug*, i.e., something like exigent circumstances).

If you don’t want to answer a question, they recommend to say that you don’t want to answer.

If you don’t agree to a test, the police may bring you to a police station where they may e.g. take a blood sample.

#### Identity check

You do have to

- answer questions for determining your identity, i.e.:

  - name
  - birthday
  - birthplace
  - home address
  - nationality
- show your identity document (if carrying it with you).

You don’t have to

- answer any other questions (e.g., where you are coming from or going to).

If you don’t answer the questions for determining your identity, the police may bring you to a police station, and/or frisk you (only allowed in certain  circumstances).

Comment: I'd like to add that generally, if the police threatens you or forces their way, e.g. into your car, I wouldn't recommend resisting, but clearly stating that you object to this. That doesn't seem very useful, but in some situations, not speaking up can lead to you accepting their actions, with potential legal consequences. Not sure in how far this applies to the locale, perhaps someone can clarify further

Comment: Just saying: Showing your driving license paper is also proof of identity, so (1) is covered by that. And with your identity, if you’re German, the police can check that you have a driving license. Driving without license is a major offence, driving without the paper is a quite minor offence.

Comment: Just to add to this, just because you don't need to answer a question, that does NOT mean that you're allowed to lie!

Comment: @Robb, there are some situations where you are allowed to lie to _illegal_ questions. For example if you are asked whether you are pregnant during a job interview you are allowed to lie. But often the police is allowed to _ask_ questions that you are not required to answer.